# Codeigniter HMVC in remote server return error

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-insert, remote-server

(my english not correct)

Please, i use HMVC in codeigniter in local well but in my remote server, thi error appear

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Home_model
>
> Filename: /home/mysite/public_html/system/core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 344
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/mysite/public_html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
> Line: 213 Function: model
>
> File:
> /home/mysite/public_html/application/modules/home/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 143 Function: model
>
> File:
> /home/mysite/public_html/application/modules/home/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 92 Function: _insert
>
> File: /home/mysite/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: Module 'mysql' already loaded
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

My files look likes:

> ->Modules
>
> --->home
>
> --------->controllers
>
> -------------->Home.php
>
> --------->models
>
> -------------->home_model.php
>
> --------->views
>
> -------------->contact.php

When i change the model file to "Home_model.php" i have this new error

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI::$db
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 77
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> /home/mysite/public_html/application/modules/home/models/Home_model.php
> Line: 44 Function: __get
>
> File:
> /home/mysite/public_html/application/modules/home/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 144 Function: _insert
>
> File:
> /home/mysite/public_html/application/modules/home/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 92 Function: _insert
>
> File: /home/mysite/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null in
> /home/mysite/public_html/application/modules/home/models/Home_model.php
> on line 44 A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/mysite/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 564
>
> Backtrace:
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function insert() on null
>
> Filename: models/Home_model.php
>
> Line Number: 44
>
> Backtrace:

I used this HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

I think the problem is when i try to use database, but i don't know where.

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Can you show us your model declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the database.

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }

}
```

or

```
$this->load->model('home_model', NULL, TRUE);
```

*third param loads db for you in model

Comment: Thanks a lot!   I just load database in the class model  $this->load->database(); after respect the case sensitive recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Model should be UCfirst and from the file structure you showed looks like its not.

So instead of home_model.php change it to Home_model.php.

Same goes to the class declaration, you want:

```
class Home_model extends CI_model
```

and not:

```
class home_model extends CI_model
```

I'm assuming that your local environment is windows and tour remote one is linux that's why this happens, because linux is case sensitive and windows is not.

So take a real good look at all your classes (models and controllers) they should all follow this pattern.